# Is it safe to convert type of a unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, casting, unique-ptr

```
template <class T> class Foo {};

class Manager {
    std::unordered_map<size_t, std::unique_ptr<std::vector<void *>>> _mFoos;

public:
    template <class T> void addFoo(Foo<T> &foo) {
        int x = typeid(T).hash_code();

        // Safe ? :
        auto &p = *(reinterpret_cast<std::unique_ptr<std::vector<Foo<T>>> *>(&_mFoos[x]));

        if (p == nullptr) {
            p.reset(new std::vector<Foo<T>>);
        }

        auto &foos = *p;
        foos.push_back(foo);
    };

    template <class T> Foo<T> &getFoo(int index) {
        int x = typeid(T).hash_code();
        auto it = _mFoos.find(x);

        auto &foos = *(reinterpret_cast<std::vector<Foo<T>> *>(it->second.get()));

        return foos[index];
    };
};
```

Is it safe and portable to reinterpret_cast a unique_ptr< T > in a unique_ptr< T2 > if T and T2 are two different types ? Does they have the same size and the same bit pattern ?

Comment: As a side note, I think that your pointers are not at the right places. You have pointer to a `vector` and then a `vector` of pointers.

Comment: Please, 1 question at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Casting between unrelated types (and different template instances are unrelated types) is undefined behavior according to the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: Ok thank you, so instead using unique_ptr, can I use void * (and manage pointer's ownership myself), is it ok with the strict aliasing rule ( std::vector<T> * -> void * -> std::vector<T> * ) ?

Comment: `unique_ptr` isn't the problem here at all :-) As noted by others, it has no impact on the casting behavior.

If you have two distinct types then it makes no sense to store them in a single vector. Especially if you allow a generic `get()` method.

Comment: The getFoo method is also a templated method, I know all the types I need at the compile time, it's why I want to avoid any virtual method / dynamic polymorphism, All I need to have is a container (unordered_map) which holds different types but because it's impossible, I create a new object of a type then cast its pointer to a generic type (void *) to save it into container but each time I use this object I know its true type because I access it only by a templated method which is called with the correct type.

Comment: And for the call of the correct destructors for the contained objects when unordered_map is destroyed, I save a destructor wrapper function address also in another unordered_map.

Answer (score 2):

> (**sidenote** Apparently I'm required to state the obvious: don't reinterpret_cast, please. See [When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used))

With shared_ptr you could use

- You can use http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast

For unique_ptr you'll have to do the conversion with move. C++17 implements the converting constructor:

```
template<class U> explicit unique_ptr( U p );
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr

> 2-4) in the specialization for arrays behave the same as the constructors that take a pointer parameter in 
>   the primary template except that they will only participate in overload resolution if either 
>   `U` is the same type as pointer, or 
>   pointer is the same type as `element_type*` and `U` is some pointer type `V*` such that `V(*)[]` is implicitly convertible to `element_type(*)[]`.

Comment: That would require the underlying types to be actually related.

Comment: I've since added the relevant snips. Of course, the types must be related (but that has nothing to do with unique_ptr)

Comment: Well, yeah. But `unique_ptr` is only part of the question. He is also asking whether it is safe cast between `vector<void*>` and `vector<Foo<T>>`.

Answer (score 0):

The normal rules apply; you can only `reinterpret_cast` the results of `.get()` to a type if the `unique_ptr` was constructed with a pointer of that type.

The behaviour of casting to any other type is undefined.